# How can add style lumo default to component?

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I try use Select component, and try to use Variant style, but  doesn't apply. I know, vaadin has default style as Lumo, how can I add this style to component. My select is vaadin-select-2.2.0

This can not work because SelectVariant cannot be resolved to a variable

```
Select<String> field = new Select<>();
field.setLabel("Group");
field.setItems("A", "B", "C", "D");
field.addThemeVariants(
    SelectVariant.LUMO_SMALL,
    SelectVariant.LUMO_ALIGN_RIGHT,
    SelectVariant.LUMO_HELPER_ABOVE_FIELD
);
```

And I try add a CSS default to select component, but it does not change (picture attachment)
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/select

```
field.addClassName("vaadin-select"); 
field.getElement().setAttribute("class", "vaadin-select");
field.getElement().setAttribute("theme", "vaadin-select");
```

The result is showing without CSS

[image]

So, how can I do it with CSS ?

Comment: Could you describe how you created your application in the first place? 2.2.0 is a very old version of the Select component, and that image you posted looks nothing like the Vaadin Select component.

Comment: Hi, I create new .java file, after that `import` the component `import com.vaadin.flow.component.select.Select;`  , and then i create new object Select like above .

Comment: Ok so what I meant to ask is: Are you building that app based on the Vaadin Flow framework, and if so, which version of Vaadin?

Comment: Ok, i use Gradle, and Vaadin version 14, build with eclipse.

Comment: Is this an existing application that you're continuing developing, or did you just start building it? Because if this is a new Vaadin app that you've just started working on, I would recommend generating a new project through start.vaadin.com

Answer (score 0):

> SelectVariant cannot be resolved to a variable

If you get that message as an error from the compiler, then the first thing to look for is to make sure you have an `import` statement for the `SelectVariant` class in the beginning of you Java file.

```java
import com.vaadin.flow.component.select.SelectVariant;
```

Comment: I try this way, but after i clicked save button, this disappear. That's why i can not use `field.addThemeVariants(SelectVariant.LUMO_SMALL);` . By the way, i will try get style default of Select component `field.getElement().setAttribute("theme","vaadin-select");` , but it's still not work.

Comment: i have added more detail in my question.